# Listing authors from SVN history including deleted (not merged) branches

Tags: svn

I'm migrating an [open source project](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/svn.en.aspx) form Subversion to git and I'm having a bit of an issue creating the authors file:

At one point, someone deleted a branch in SVN. He didn't merge it back, just deleted it. As a result when I run `svn log -g --quiet -r 1:HEAD`, the result does not include any commits made on the deleted branch. This means my final SVN users list is missing anyone who only commited to this, delete, branch.

So far, I have been unable to find a syntax for SVN that would include all such users. They are necessary becaue the git migration process is unforgiving. it will track this deleted branch and therefore need the users.

Any suggestion?

**Edit:** I bit the bullet and manually added all users to my authors file. In order to do that, I found the commit which deleted the branch and grabbed a log up to that point: that got me all the missing commits.

**Edit2:** The repo that I'm working on is here: https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10 and can be accessed in read-only mode with the user name **Indy-Public-RO**. The problematic tree deletions happens in revision 4493 and 4494.
You can verify the problem by trying to pull the logs 1216-1219 (`svn log -g --quiet -r 1200:1220` for instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your log command with the repository's **absolute base URL** (i.e. the top-most folder of the repository) like for example:

```
svn log http://your-server.com/svn/your-repo -g --quiet -r 1:HEAD
```

I've just tried that with an old repository of mine and the log wasn't missing a single revision.

**Edit 1:** I see that you've solved your problem, but I wanted to expand on the above method - I'm quite convinced that this should work. Consider the following script to create a repo and do some work:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p ~/tmp/svntest
cd ~/tmp/svntest
svnadmin create ~/tmp/svntest/repo
svn co file:///home/oink/tmp/svntest/repo wc
svn mkdir wc/trunk wc/branches wc/tags
svn ci wc -m "created repo structure" --username user1
echo change1 > wc/trunk/test.txt
svn add wc/trunk/test.txt
svn ci wc -m "committed change1 to trunk" --username user2
svn cp wc/trunk wc/branches/branch1
svn ci wc -m "created branch1" --username user3
echo change2 > wc/branches/branch1/test.txt
svn ci wc -m "committed change2 to branch1" --username user4
svn up wc
svn del wc/branches/branch1
svn ci wc -m "removed branch1" --username user5
svn log wc -g --quiet -r 1:HEAD
```

The output of the last command includes the commit to the deleted, unmerged branch:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | user1 | 2018-03-02 10:57:48 +0100 (Fri, 02 Mar 2018)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | user2 | 2018-03-02 10:57:49 +0100 (Fri, 02 Mar 2018)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | user3 | 2018-03-02 10:57:49 +0100 (Fri, 02 Mar 2018)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | user4 | 2018-03-02 10:57:49 +0100 (Fri, 02 Mar 2018)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r5 | user5 | 2018-03-02 10:57:50 +0100 (Fri, 02 Mar 2018)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Edit 2:** Thanks for posting the repository URL! Let's just use absolute numbers here. This repository has 5448 revisions, at the time of writing. When I do...

```
svn log https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10 -g --quiet --username Indy-Public-RO > tmp.txt
grep -E "^r" tmp.txt | wc -l
```

...the output I get is:

```
5448
```

This means we're looking at all revisions, right? We just need to harvest the usernames...

```
grep -E "^r" tmp.txt | cut -d"|" -f2 | sort | uniq
```

...to get the complete list of committers:

```
 Andreas Hausladen
 Andrew Neillans
 ArvidWinkelsdorf
 (...cut for brevity...)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work for deleted branches that haven't been merged

Comment: @Stephane: That is weird, see my edit why I think this absolutely should work.

Comment: Try adding a commit to the trunk after the branch deletion. In any case, if you feel like checking it out, I'll add the refs to the repo that causes me trouble: it's an open source project

Comment: @Stephane: Yes, please share that repository URL, I'll check it out as I have the time!

Comment: In case you missed it, I added the repository information to the question

Comment: @Stephane: Cool! I just checked that repository - can you please look at my update and see if I missed anything there?

Comment: Looks like you're right. I have no idea why my script didn't return all the addresses. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I ran it on Windows: I ran your version on Linux and I do have all the names. Thank you and sorry for all the trouble

Comment: @Stephane: Glad to have helped! :) Fun fact: I wrote the above on Windows cmd using Windows ports of the used tools (but verified on Linux as well).